# Strange java print output

Tags: java, println

I am new to Java and was working with simple printing. First, I executed:

```
System.out.println(1 + 2 + "3");
```

**Output:**`33`

I made up logic that 1 and 2 will be added and 3 will be printed as is.

Then, I tried this:

```
System.out.println ("1" + 2 + 3);
```

**Output:**`123`

Applying that logic I got answer 15 ,couldn't work-out the correct answer, so I need your help, SO friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `+` is evaluated from the left so your second example is interpreted this way:

```
System.out.println (((“1”+2)+3));
====================> "12"+3
====================> "123"
```

If you want to display `15` then you should do the following:

```
System.out.println (“1”+(2+3));
```

This way `(2+3)` will be evaluated first.

Answer (score 2):

1. The expression `1 + 2` is an `int`.
   You're then concatenating `"3"` to that int.
2. The expression `"1" + 2` is a `String`.
   You're then concatenating `3` to that `String`.

You're thinking of `"1" + (2 + 3)`, which doesn't happen because Java is left-associative.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case Java adds the numbers to get the result 3 and the appending of the string 3 causes it to become the concatenated string: "33".

In the second case the result is a string because of the "1" and the others get concatenated to become "123"